# When adding a fragment Tabs on drawerOption

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, android-actionbaractivity

I have in my MainActivity one drawerOption. Where you can select multiple Fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView drawerList;
private String[] drawerOptions;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[]{
                                               new MainFragment(),
                                               new AcordesFragment(),
                                               new AfinadorFragment(),
                                               new AboutFragment(),
                                               new ExitFragment(),
};
```

I would like to pray to select a Fragmet, this contains several tabs.
The source of my code fragment is as follows:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class AcordesFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBarActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tab.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        actionbar.addTab(
                actionbar.newTab()
                        .setText("Tab" +i)
                        .setTabListener(tabListener)
        );
    }

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acordes, container, false);
}


}
```

But it does not work the following line: public class AcordesFragment extends Fragment implements ActionBarActivity

Thank you very much for your help. I'm learning a lot

Answer (score 0):

man  fragment can not implements a ActionBarActivity .Only,Activity can implements ActionBarActivity.

If, you want to add a tabs in Fagment you have to use TabSlidingTabLayout.
This is the xml part .
        
You Have to download this library.

1. [Download The Zip](https://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/SlidingTabsBasic.zip).
2. [developers.google.com/SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)